# having trouble injecting nested Recyclerview adapter in android using dagger 2

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, dagger-2

below is my child adapter

```
public class ChildModalitiesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildModalitiesAdapter.ChildModalityViewHolder> {

    private List<DynamicModalities.ChildModality> childModalities=new ArrayList<>();

    @Inject
    public ChildModalitiesAdapter() {
    }

    public void setChildModalities(List<DynamicModalities.ChildModality> childModalities) {
        this.childModalities = new ArrayList<>();
        this.childModalities = childModalities;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChildModalityViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ChildModalityViewHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                , R.layout.item_child_modality, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChildModalityViewHolder childModalityViewHolder, int i) {
        childModalityViewHolder.setData(childModalities.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return childModalities.size();
    }


    static class ChildModalityViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ItemChildModalityBinding mBinding;

        ChildModalityViewHolder(ItemChildModalityBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.mBinding = binding;
        }

        void setData(DynamicModalities.ChildModality childModality) {
            mBinding.setChildModality(childModality);
        }
    }

}
```

below is my parent adapter

```
public class ModalitiesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ModalitiesAdapter.ModalitiesViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;

    private List<DynamicModalities> dynamicModalities = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setDynamicModalities(List<DynamicModalities> dynamicModalities) {
        this.dynamicModalities = new ArrayList<>();
        this.dynamicModalities = dynamicModalities;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Inject
    public ModalitiesAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ModalitiesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ModalitiesViewHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                , R.layout.item_modality, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ModalitiesViewHolder modalitiesViewHolder, int i) {
        modalitiesViewHolder.setData(dynamicModalities.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dynamicModalities.size();
    }

    public class ModalitiesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @Inject
        ChildModalitiesAdapter childAdapter;

        private ItemModalityBinding mBinding;

        public ModalitiesViewHolder(ItemModalityBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());

            this.mBinding = binding;
            this.mBinding.setModalitiesViewHolder(this);
        }

        public void setData(DynamicModalities data) {

            mBinding.setDynamicModality(data);


            mBinding.rvChildModalities.addItemDecoration(
                    new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration((int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin4)));


            mBinding.rvChildModalities.setAdapter(childAdapter);

            //**getting adpter null pointer exception here at below line**
            childAdapter.setChildModalities(data.getChildModality()); 

        }


    }

}
```

> getting child adapter null pointer exception, commented in code where exactly.

I have a functionality where I need to use nested recyclerview, thats why I used parent child nested adapters, but parent is getting injected and not the child, how to inject the child like parent?

Comment: Why inject adapters from Dagger at all? Are you ever going to have a different implementation that is provided as a mock or a fake?

Comment: Yeah I am going to have a different implementation too!

Comment: I've been working on Android apps for over 5 years and not once have I seen a usecase for swapping out 1 adapter to another adapter in a Fragment. But I do think Groupie is a better abstraction over RecyclerView.Adapters than most of them.

Comment: can you give an example what you are saying, or provide a reference.

Comment: You can check out GroupAdapter in Groupie like in https://github.com/lisawray/groupie/blob/c3411d814f18e9b308e3b829b1e8a532f34b6ee2/example/src/main/java/com/xwray/groupie/example/MainActivity.kt#L114